# Python won't find installed module when run as child process within Electron app

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I'm having some trouble trying to run a python script within Electron using the **child_process** module.
I recently installed Anaconda on my computer (OSX 10.11.2) and created this script:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf

# read dataset file
filename = "/path/to/my/dataset.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False)

# esecute SQL-like query
q = '''
SELECT * FROM df
'''
syr_subset = sqldf(q, globals())

# print result
print syr_subset.to_json()
```

If I run this script in the terminal with **python myscript.py** everything works just fine (the script loads a csv file using pandas, performs a query and returns the result).

However, if I try to run the same script inside Electron, like this:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('python -u /path/to/myscript.py',
  function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ', stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ', stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ', error);
    }
});
```

I get an error.

stderr contains this:

```
stderr:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

And the captured error contains this:

```
cmd: "/bin/sh -c python -u /path/to/myscript.py"
message: 
Command failed: /bin/sh -c python -u /path/to/myscript.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/myscript.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pandas as pd
      ImportError: No module named pandas
```

So it looks like this script, when run within Electron, can't find the pandas library (let me repeat that this does not happen when run in the terminal, everything works just fine there). I'm not using virtualenv as far as I'm aware.

Again within Electron, I executed **which python**, returning **/usr/bin/python**.

If I execute **which python** in the Terminal, though, it returns **/Users/myusername/anaconda2/bin/python**.

I don't quite get why Electron seems to run a different binary than the default one I run in the Terminal.

Finally, in order to test this more easily as the real code is embeded in a larger Electron app, I created a new Electron project and ran exactly the same code (the snippet I pasted above). Surprisingly, everything works just fine there. So, two different Electron apps but apparently running the same code: in one case it doesn't work (seems to run different python binaries) and in the other it works.

Any idea what could be going on here?

Many thanks.

Comment: did that work for you after you'd packaged your app too?

Answer (score 3):

I finally solved it by removing my Anaconda installation and re-installing the python modules with pip. Not sure what was causing the problem, but this solution is enough for my needs now.