# PYTHON module "requests" not working with packaged electron app

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, electron, electron-packager

In my electron app I have a python file that has two import statements shown below

```
import requests
import shutil
```

The app works fine without an errors in the IDE but after packaging the electron app with

`npx electron-packager ./ --platform=darwin --icon=src/img/logo.icns`

The app gives me this error
[image: Uncaught Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests']

It only gives this error for the 'requests' module but not the 'shutil' module. And yes, 'requests' is installed on my computer. I also use the [PythonShell module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell) in the js file to run the python file like below

```
function version_checker(){
    form.classList.toggle('hide');
    circle.classList.toggle('show');
    let pyshell = new PythonShell(__dirname + '/version_checker.py');

    pyshell.on('message', function (message){
        console.log(message);
        if(message !== "same"){
            console.log("updating")
        }
        else{

            if(message !== "restart"){
                form.classList.toggle('hide');
                circle.classList.toggle('show');
            }
            else{}
        }
    })
    pyshell.end(function (err,code,signal) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The exit code was: ' + code);
        console.log('The exit signal was: ' + signal);
        console.log('finished');
    });
}
```

I also do not wish to compile the python file into an executable because the python script "talks" to the js file. I am also on a M1 Pro Macbook running macOS Ventrua if that helps

**How do I package the app and include the 'requests' module  OR  How do I make the 'requests' module work with the packaged app**

I did find a [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493166/python-module-not-found-after-packaging-electron-app) that asked a similar question but the owner voluntary took down the question so I wasn't able to view it

I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35367396/python-wont-find-installed-module-when-run-as-child-process-within-electron-app) but it wasn't helpful because I'm not using 'anaconda' or 'child-process'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the error is ModuleNotFoundError, then your python interpreter is struggling to find the requests module. This can happen for a number of reasons:

1. Module does not exist: We can rule this out if your ide ran program successfully.

2: Module is not where interpreter expects to find it: Most likely.

Almost certainly the python interpreter used by your IDE is different to the one you ran after packaging the electron app.

The solution is to either:

a. make sure the location of requests is visible to the PYTHONPATH by setting that in the proper location (I don't use MAC but I believe you have ~/.bash_profile file to set it in or

b. Explicitly add the request module location via a sys.path.append command in your code eg

```
import sys
import os

path = 'your path to request module'
sys.path.append(os.path.join(path, 'requests')

import requests
```

You should be able to find the path location by investigating your IDE and looking where you set the module to be included in your program

Answer (score 2):

PythonShell just calls the system's Python interpreter, so use PIP to install the requests library

Or specify the interpreter as follows:

```js
new PythonShell(__dirname + '/version_checker.py', {
  pythonPath: '/path/to/python'
})
```

Note: For production purposes, it is recommended to include an interpreter in electron and install dependencies

It seems you just want to make a HTTP request, why not try [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in javascript?